# Unsupported index type: NULL --> plotly chart in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I am getting an error with the plotting index using plotly in conjunction with reactive values in shiny. The sidebar panel loads with no issues but there is a problem displaying the chart that I cannot determine. Any help solving the index problem would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

data(economics, package = "ggplot2")


nms <- names(economics) 

ui <- fluidPage(

  headerPanel("TEST"),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput('x', 'X', choices = nms, selected = nms[[1]]),
    selectInput('y', 'Y', choices = nms, selected = nms[[2]]),
    sliderInput('plotHeight', 'Height of plot (in pixels)', 
                min = 100, max = 2000, value = 1000)
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotlyOutput('trendPlot', height = "900px")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  #add reactive data information. Dataset = built in diamonds data
  dataset  <- reactive({economics[, c(input$xcol, input$ycol)]
  })

  output$trendPlot <- renderPlotly({

    # build graph with ggplot syntax
    p <- ggplot(dataset(), aes_string(x = input$x, y = input$y)) + 
      geom_line()


    ggplotly(p) %>% 
      layout(height = input$plotHeight, autosize=TRUE)

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

> Warning: Error in : Unsupported index type: NULL

Comment: Replace `xcol` and `ycol` to `x` and `y` in your `reactive` code, because there are no `inputId` with the names of `xcol, ycol`. i.e, `dataset  <- reactive({economics[, c(input$x, input$y)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mistakenly used `xcol` and `ycol` not sure why. Without those names the code works fine.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)

data(economics, package = "ggplot2")


nms <- names(economics) 

ui <- fluidPage(

  headerPanel("TEST"),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput('x', 'X', choices = nms, selected = nms[[1]]),
    selectInput('y', 'Y', choices = nms, selected = nms[[2]]),
    sliderInput('plotHeight', 'Height of plot (in pixels)', 
                min = 100, max = 2000, value = 1000)
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotlyOutput('trendPlot', height = "900px")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  #add reactive data information. Dataset = built in diamonds data
  dataset  <- reactive({
    economics[, c(input$x, input$y)]

  })

  output$trendPlot <- renderPlotly({


    # build graph with ggplot syntax
    p <- ggplot(dataset(), aes_string(input$x, input$y)) + 
      geom_line()


    ggplotly(p, height = input$plotHeight)

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: @ amrrs, thanks very much. I repleced the code, I now get, Theme element 'text' has NULL property: margin, debug

Comment: Warning: Error in ggplot2::calc_element: Theme element 'text' has NULL property: margin, debug
  [No stack trace available]

Comment: strange I'm not getting that warning. when are you getting it?

Comment: It shows up in Red where the chart should be displayed once the app is running.

Comment: @Joe did you use the code in my answer and it does?

Comment: @Joe try this updated code where I've removed layout

Comment: Thank you, but no change. Still displays, Warning: Error in ggplot2::calc_element: Theme element 'text' has NULL property: margin, debug [No stack trace available] – Joe 34 mins ago

Comment: Can you try to uninstall your tidyverse and install back?

Comment: Wow. That worked! How did you guess that was the issue??

Comment: I thought probably some old `ggplot2` package functions could be the issue. Ideally i should have shared my `sessionInfo()` and compared it with yours but anyways, glad it got fixed!